# Loudspeaker Tile in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

In the classical desktop I have the loudspeaker symbol, which I use to make the sound louder and quieter by using the mouse.

On the modern UI Start Screen I can change it through the Charm-Bar and settings, but it is inconvenient.

Is there some fast access to the loudspeaker for example through a tile?

Here is the screenshot of the usual loudspeaker:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

This option still exists on the desktop under notifications.  It is two clicks, but faster than the charm bar.